# Hacer filas de una tabla collapsable con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy intentando crear una tabla en la que una fila hace de cabecera de un grupo de filas que vienen a continuación.

Al cargar la tabla se han de ver todas las filas (**cabeceras** y **detalles**) y al pulsar en una cabecera, esconderse o "**plegarse**" sus filas de detalle.

Para ello estoy probando con la clase "**`collapse`**" de **bootstrap** (**versión 4**).

El código es este:

```
 <table id="datoscuentas" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
       <tr>
          <th>Cuenta</th>
          <th>Impuestos</th>
          <th>Transferencias</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @{
       var empresaTemp = String.Empty;
       for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
       {
          if (empresaTemp != Model[i].NomEmpresa)
          {
             <tr>
                <td colspan="8">
                   <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@i">
                      @Html.DisplayFor(x => @Model[i].NomEmpresa, new { @id = "NomEmpresa_" + i, @class = "form-control" })
                   </span>
                </td>
             </tr>
             empresaTemp = Model[i].NomEmpresa;
          }
          <tr id="@i" class="collapse in">
             <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Cuenta, new { @id = "Cuenta_" + i, @class = "form-control" })</td>
             <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Impuestos, new { @id = "Impuestos_" + i, @class = "form-control" })</td>
             <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Transferencias, new { @id = "Transferencias_" + i, @class = "form-control" })</td>

             @Html.HiddenFor(x => @Model[i].CuentaID, new { @id = "CuentaID_" + i })
          </tr>
       }
    }
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Pero no me aparecen las filas de detalle y al pulsar en la "**empresa**" no se despliegan tampoco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he encontrado una solución y la comparto aquí por si a alguien le sirve.

```
 <table id="datoscuentas" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
           <th>Cuenta</th><th>Impuestos</th><th>Transferencias</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     @{
        var empresaTemp = String.Empty;
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
           if (empresaTemp != Model[i].NomEmpresa)
           {
                empresaTemp = Model[i].NomEmpresa;
              <tbody>
                 <tr class="clickable" data-target="#@empresaTemp" aria-controls="@empresaTemp" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" >
                    <td colspan="8">
                       <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@i">
                          @Html.DisplayFor(x => @Model[i].NomEmpresa, new { @id = "NomEmpresa_" + i, @class = "form-control" })
                       </span>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
           }
             <tbody id="@empresaTemp" class="collapse show">
              <tr>
                 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Cuenta, new { @id = "Cuenta_" + i, @class = "form-control" })</td>
                 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Impuestos, new { @id = "Impuestos_" + i, @class = "form-control" })</td>
                 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Transferencias, new { @id = "Transferencias_" + i, @class = "form-control" })</td>

                 @Html.HiddenFor(x => @Model[i].CuentaID, new { @id = "CuentaID_" + i })
              </tr>
             </tbody>
        }
     }
     </tbody>
 </table>
```